# JQuery wrap <li> elements to create nested lists

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of li elements with classes representing their type (ordered or unordered) and their list level (2 is a sublist, 3 is a sublist of a sublist etc.)

I need to wrap them up in the  /  tags correctly but I haven't figured out how yet.

Example:

```
<li class="ordered O1">
<li class="ordered O1">
<li class="unordered O2">
<li class="ordered O1">
```

Should be:

```
<ol>
<li class="ordered O1">
<li class="ordered O1">
<ul>
<li class="unordered O2">
</ul>
<li class="ordered O1">
</ol>
```

Comment: The way HTML does lists is kind of jacked (https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Jacked). Is there any possibility of switching the input txt to wiki format? Wiki text format is both easier and safer

Comment: That is not valid HTML you want

Comment: Can there be multiple unordered elements together?

Comment: @epascarello it's not? how does HTML handle nested lists then?

Comment: @ControlAltDel Unfortunately not, the input text comes from PowerPoint and it's in the clipboard... And powerpoint BARELY gives me enough information to guess how the lists look MOST OF THE TIME. So, yeah, pretty frustrating.

Comment: @epascarello I don't know what HTML allows, but in principle yes, any sort of combination has to work

Comment: @epascarello There is no invalidity problem with what OP wants.

Comment: @connexo the way it was written it is, but yes it can be valid or we would not have nested lists.

Answer (score 1):

It can be done with creating some new element and replacing it. Since it is tagged with jQuery, I will use that since it makes it a bit easier.

```js
function cleanUpListItems (list, type, level) {

  // find the first one that is 
  const unItem = $(list).find(`> li.${type}.${level}`).eq(0);

  // If we have unordered lets move it
  if (unItem.length) {
    // figure out where we are moving it
    const prevLi = unItem.prev("li");

    // find all the unordered elements in that group
    const groupedLis = unItem.nextUntil(`:not(.${level})`).addBack();

     
    // create the nested list and add it
    const ul = type === "unordered" ? $("<ul></ul>") : $("<ol></ol>");
    ul.append(groupedLis);
    prevLi.append(ul);
    
    cleanUpListItems (list, type, level)
  }
}

function cleanUpList(list) {

  // find what tha max ident level is so we know what we need to start with
  const maxIndent = Math.max(...list.find("> li").map(function (e) { 
    return +this.className.match(/O(\d+)/)[1] }
  )); 

  // start from the top to the bottom, moving items into the li before it
  for (var i = maxIndent; i > 1; i--) {
    cleanUpListItems(list, "ordered", `O${i}`);
    cleanUpListItems(list, "unordered", `O${i}`); 
  }

  // check if the list is the correct type, if not swap it
  if (list.find("li:eq(0)").is(".ordered")) {
    const newList = $("<ol></ol>");
    newList.append(list.children());
    list.replaceWith(newList);
  }
}

cleanUpList($(".myList"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="myList">
  <li class="ordered O1">1 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O1">2 o</li>
  <li class="unordered O2">2.1 u</li>
  <li class="ordered O1">3 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O1">4 o</li>
  <li class="unordered O2">4.1 u</li>
  <li class="unordered O2">4.2 u</li>
  <li class="ordered O3">4.2.1 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O3">4.2.2 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O3">4.2.3 o</li>
  <li class="unordered O2">4.3 u</li>
  <li class="unordered O3">4.3 u</li>
  <li class="unordered O3">4.3 u</li>
  <li class="unordered O3">4.3 u</li>
  <li class="ordered O1">5 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O2">5.1 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O2">5.2 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O3">5.2.1 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O3">5.2.1 o</li>
  <li class="ordered O1">6 o</li>
</ul>
```